# How to inherit from array built in class in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a class that inherits from base array class, and just add some new functionality for the sake of learning.

Now when I try using this code

```cpp
class checkInherit : public array
```

Error is

```
C++ argument list for class template is missing
```

Which I think is that I have to add some arguments. When I Peeked into Array built in array code, this is the code

```cpp
// TUPLE INTERFACE TO array
template <class _Ty, size_t _Size>
class array;

template <class _Ty, size_t _Size>
struct tuple_size<array<_Ty, _Size>>
    : integral_constant<size_t, _Size> { // struct to determine number of elements in array
```

Now is there any way I can do this?

EDIT:
My assignment at University is to make circular queue using built in arrays. Now What my thought is that If I somehow inherits from `std::array` and add some extra functions in it to make it act as circular queue. It might not be possible but at least I want to inherit `std::array` so that I can give it a try.

Comment: You shouldn't inherit from types that do not have a virtual destructor.  What is the extra functionality you're trying to add?

Comment: I am given the assignment of the circular queue with array in my university. I thought why not inherit from the built-in an array and add the functionality which makes it circular queue.

Comment: @AhmadAnis - I'd suggest your problem is better solved with composition instead of inheritance.  If you want to use inheritance though, you need to provide the template arguments (e.g., `class checkInherit : public std::array<int, 17>`).

Comment: @StephenNewell, It is giving error of `TUPLE INTERFACE TO array` at `std::array` and `incomplete type is not allowed1` at `<int,17>`

Comment: @AhmadAnis -- What you are probably looking for is a container adapter.  Look at [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) for example.  By default, a `std::deque` is used as the container, but can be changed using a template argument.

Comment: It is working with `class checkInherit : public stack <int>`

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question. We have trouble reading in your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `array` is the standard [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) template, I won't recommend inheriting from it.

> I want to make a class that inherits from base array class, and just add some new functionality for the sake of learning.

**That smells like a very bad idea.** Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then a [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

If you really want to do that, be sure to follow the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).

You might want to have a member in your `class checkInherit`  which is some `std::array`, and redefine the appropriate member functions and `operator`s.

This is just a guess.

Comment: Yea, I guess this is not a good idea, and I will do it with member in my `class` which is `std::array`. Thanks